# What element type i need to use similar to LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am pretty new to Android, but just trying to develop a small application similar to "User survey"

User is displayed with multiple questions(Activity1), once he answers all questions a Summary of questions with selected options needs to be displayed(Activity2).

I wanted to use some element/container like LinearLayout, which holds Questions and Options with some border to separate each question. Here Android wont allow more than one LinerLayout.

So is there any other element type similar to LinearLayout that is useful here?

Comment: use listView or recyclerview to show multiple linear layouts..

Comment: recycler view or gridview with custom child layout

Answer (score 0):

You can provide style to your linear layout with border and place it in drawable. after that you can set background for linear layout. The file under drawable can be writen as follows

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
<corners
  android:radius="2dp"
  android:topRightRadius="0dp"
  android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
  android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" />
<stroke
  android:width="1dp"
  android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make root layout, within it make another two layout which contains your questions and result elements, make one of some visibility invisible which you don't need at this moment, then do the same for other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TableLayout and customize your view accordingly.
Since you have to display a list of questions and answers please add views programmatically. It will create less code and quite readable and you do need to add layout every time for a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really new to android, and you want just to throw view inside of it, meaning, add `CheckedTextView`'s inside of a vertical oriented `LinearLayout`, and that LinearLayout to be inside of a `ScrollView`. Also maybe checkout this link, ths may help you do what you need:
https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 0):

Android does allow multiple LinearLayouts.You just have to place them in the right place. You can also use the combination of relative and linear layouts. or you can do like this :

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Question1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Option1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Option2"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Option3"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Option4"/>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Question2"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Option1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Option2"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Option3"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Option4"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can also use constraint layout to position your views.Get the detailed info about contraint layout from here : https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-new-android-constraintlayout-eed37fe8d8f1

Comment: My question is more about how to place multiple LineraLayouts in scrollView.

Comment: why do you need to put multiple a LinearLayout in ScrollView when you can do it by putting your root LinearLayout in the ScrollView.You can use my code for reference, just put the root LinearLayout inside ScrollView.

Comment: Ajay, i have a root LinearLayout, in that i have ScrollView. This ScrollView should contain all survey "Question and selected answers". I would like to keep question and radiogroup's options into LinearLayout for each question along with options.